# Track sms,mmsand location through j2me

Tags: java-me, mobile, sms, location, call

I m working in j2me project where i have to build application of tracking one's phone.In this application i want to track one mobile i.e the incoming and outgoing sms,mms,call,location etc.

Tracking should work like i want to save all the data(incoming and outgoing sms, mms, call ,location) into my server.And the server can send that data to another mobile.So that person can track the one's mobile from other.

Plz anyone help me and explain me is it possible in j2me.
if yes then plz help me and send me some code

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve with j2me for tracking the incoming and outgoing SMS, Call and MMS. But you can tracking the Location. See this links for your reference.

[Nokia forum](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?125165-location-tracking-system-using-j2me)

[Location based service](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/developing-location-based-services-introducing-location-api-j2me)